# Qt dependencies not found

Tags: macos, qt, bitcoin

I am trying to compile the bitcoin-core on my Mac and I want to use QT to develop the project also. Here is the instruction on GitHub:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.14/doc/build-osx.md

And I have set up my QT:

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5.5/5.5.1_1/lib
```

then when i run 
`./configure --with-gui`
it throws the error below:

```
checking for Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Widgets... no
checking for QtCore QtGui QtNetwork... no
configure: error: Qt dependencies not found
```

and i can't run ./src/qt in QT. It throws these error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `bitcoin_qt'.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
11:24:14: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project bitocin (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
```

My English's bad, hope you could understand. Thank you for help!